# How i can save the value and index of the position in an array in ANSI C?

Tags: c, arrays, indexing, int

I just wanna know how i can save the value and the index for my array "cadenaNumeros" in a    integer, if the user entry is something like this : 123456789  or  48934013 or 183853025... etc.

I was thinking do it with a FOR, but my code didn´t work.

For example: if we have this array "123456789" the value will be 2 and index = 1 and this numbers save it in a integer.

I'm programming in ANSI C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    int a = 0, i = 0, indice, numero[20], vuelta, quedan, x;
    int cadenaNumeros[20000];
    int num, num2;

    printf("\n\nEscribe el numero de palancas: ");
    scanf("%d", &num2);

    printf("\n\nEscriba el numero de la palanca roja: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    printf("\n\nIntroduzca una cadena de numeros: ");
    scanf("%d", &cadenaNumeros);

    for(i = 0; cadenaNumeros[i] < num2; i++); {
        cadenaNumeros[0] == numero[x];
        printf("%d", numero[x]);
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cadenaNumeros[0] == numero[x];` is a no-op. Also, [why void main is bad](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#void-main).

Comment: Being a no-op is the least of that line's problems. `x` is not initialized, and probably goes out of bounds (`numero` isn't initialized as well, btw).

Comment: @chris Thats right, im working in DEV C++ 4.9, and everything runs perfect. just i can save the index and the value of my array.

Comment: There's a stray semicolon after your for loop, here `for(i = 0; cadenaNumeros[i] < num2; i++);`

Comment: its tough to read it in 'dont know' language. But it seems you can make a 'hash table' if you have big enough data structure.

Comment: you are allocating 20000 `ints` on the stack. This will lead you to an overflow because you will have less room to have bunch of hierarchical calls to functions and to allocate other on stack parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int index = -1, i = 0;

// Assuming num2 is the number you're searching for
// And the array size is 20000
for( ; i < 20000; i++) {
    if( cadenaNumeros[i] == num2) {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}

if( index != -1) {
    printf( "Found %d at index %d\n", num2, index);
} 
else {
    printf( "Number not found\n");
}
```